# Put the labels down from the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a plot like this How is it possible to put the labels of flow down from the plot

And mabel the black option more fat and put the labels of these bars now in the middle of the black column next to it

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close", "close"), 
                 stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
                 newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))

# Count the number of occurrences for each alluvial
df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(stock, newspaper, status) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) 

# Define the factors
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("open", "open/close", "close"))
df$stock <- factor(df$stock, levels = c("google", "amazon", "yahoo"))
df$newspaper <- factor(df$newspaper, levels = c("times", "newyork", "london"))

# Plot the alluvial as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format
ggplot2::ggplot(df.2, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12) +
  ggalluvial::geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  ggplot2::geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: Your description of what you want to do is very vague here. Which "labels of flow" do you mean? Do you mean the legend? Put it where? At the bottom of the plot? And what do you mean by "the black option"? Do you want the black stratum bars wider?

Answer (score 1):

The description of what you want is pretty vague. As far as I can tell, you want the legend moved to the bottom of the plot, and the stratum bars made wider:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status)) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/5, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]